# How to get value when click button on react flatpickr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, flatpickr

I have a component in React and attach react-flatpicker to get date value.
However, after I use useRef, it shows that value is "possibly null" and yes after `console.log` it is the same result:

```
<Flatpickr
    ref={fp}
    name="startTime"
    className="py-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
    options={{enableTime: true, noCalendar: true, dateFormat: "H:i",}}
/>
```

And here is the function:

```
const fp = useRef(null);
function handleSubmitAgenda() {
    console.log(fp?.current?.value);
}
```

Please enlighten me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value from the React Flatpickr component when you click a button, you need to use the `onChange` prop provided by Flatpickr.

Please check the codebase below.

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Flatpickr from "react-flatpickr";

function YourComponent() {
  const [selectedDateTime, setSelectedDateTime] = useState(null);
  const fp = useRef(null);

  // Function to handle the date/time selection change
  const handleDateTimeChange = (selectedDates) => {
    setSelectedDateTime(selectedDates[0]);
  };

  function handleSubmitAgenda() {
    console.log(selectedDateTime); // This will log the selected date/time when the button is clicked
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Flatpickr
        ref={fp}
        name="startTime"
        className="py-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
        options={{
          enableTime: true,
          noCalendar: true,
          dateFormat: "H:i",
        }}
        onChange={handleDateTimeChange} // Call handleDateTimeChange on date/time selection change
      />

      <button onClick={handleSubmitAgenda}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.
Best.